# How do I take subsets of a data frame according to a grouping in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, aggregation

I have an aggregation problem which I cannot figure out how to perform efficiently in R.

Say I have the following data:

```
group1 <- c("a","b","a","a","b","c","c","c","c",
            "c","a","a","a","b","b","b","b")
group2 <- c(1,2,3,4,1,3,5,6,5,4,1,2,3,4,3,2,1)
value  <- c("apple","pear","orange","apple",
            "banana","durian","lemon","lime",
            "raspberry","durian","peach","nectarine",
            "banana","lemon","guava","blackberry","grape")
df <- data.frame(group1,group2,value)
```

I am interested in sampling from the data frame `df` such that I randomly pick only a single row from each combination of factors `group1` and `group2`.

As you can see, the results of `table(df$group1,df$group2)`

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6
a 2 1 2 1 0 0
b 2 2 1 1 0 0
c 0 0 1 1 2 1
```

shows that some combinations are seen more than once, while others are never seen.  For those that are seen more than once (e.g., `group1="a"` and `group2=3`), I want to randomly pick only one of the corresponding rows and return a new data frame that has only that subset of rows.  That way, each possible combination of the grouping factors is represented by only a single row in the data frame.

One important aspect here is that my actual data sets can contain anywhere from 500,000 rows to >2,000,000 rows, so it is important to be mindful of performance.

I am relatively new at R, so I have been having trouble figuring out how to generate this structure correctly.  One attempt looked like this (using the `plyr` package):

```
choice <- function(x,label) {
    cbind(x[sample(1:nrow(x),1),],data.frame(state=label))
}

df <- ddply(df[,c("group1","group2","value")],
            .(group1,group2),
            pick_junc,
            label="test")
```

Note that in this case, I am also adding an extra column to the data frame called "label" which is specified as an extra argument to the `ddply` function.  However, I killed this after about 20 min.

In other cases, I have tried using `aggregate` or `by` or `tapply`, but I never know exactly what the specified function is getting, what it should return, or what to do with the result (especially for `by`).

I am trying to switch from python to R for exploratory data analysis, but this type of aggregation is crucial for me.  In python, I can perform these operations very rapidly, but it is inconvenient as I have to generate a separate script/data structure for each different type of aggregation I want to perform.

I want to love R, so please help!  Thanks!

Uri

Comment: with a data frame that large, you need to look at the package `data.table`, which is pretty fast

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the `plyr` solution

```
set.seed(1234)
ddply(df, .(group1, group2), summarize, 
     value = value[sample(length(value), 1)])
```

This gives us

```
   group1 group2      value
1       a      1      apple
2       a      2  nectarine
3       a      3     banana
4       a      4      apple
5       b      1      grape
6       b      2 blackberry
7       b      3      guava
8       b      4      lemon
9       c      3     durian
10      c      4     durian
11      c      5  raspberry
12      c      6       lime
```

EDIT. With a data frame that big, you are better off using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,list(value = value[sample(length(value), 1)]),'group1, group2']
```

EDIT 2: Performance Comparison: Data Table is ~ 15 X faster

```
group1 = sample(letters, 1000000, replace = T)
group2 = sample(LETTERS, 1000000, replace = T)
value  = runif(1000000, 0, 1)
df     = data.frame(group1, group2, value)
dt     = data.table(df)

f1_dtab = function() {
   dt[,list(value = value[sample(length(value), 1)]),'group1, group2']
}
f2_plyr = function() {ddply(df, .(group1, group2), summarize, value =          
   value[sample(length(value), 1)])
}

f3_by = function() {do.call(rbind,by(df,list(grp1 = df$group1,grp2 = df$group2),
  FUN = function(x){x[sample(nrow(x),1),]}))
}


library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(f1_dtab(), f2_plyr(), f3_by(), replications = 10)

      test  replications elapsed relative
  f1_dtab()           10   4.764  1.00000    
  f2_plyr()           10  68.261 14.32851    
    f3_by()           10  67.369 14.14127
```

Comment: No big surprise that `data.table` wins. Somehow I thought `by` would beat `ddply` by more than that, though.

Comment: So why doesn't using `by` return something that can be coerced into a data frame?  What is the `by`-type object?

Comment: @Uri Laserson: See the help page for "by" and "tapply" for what "by" returns. In this case where you should only have one value per group it may be a matrix-like object, but with additional attributes that support the by-class.

Answer (score -1):

One more way:

```
with(df, tapply(value, list( group1,  group2), length))
   1  2 3 4  5  6
a  2  1 2 1 NA NA
b  2  2 1 1 NA NA
c NA NA 1 1  2  1
# Now use tapply to sample withing groups
# `resample` fn is from the sample help page:
# Avoids an error with sample when only one value in a group.
resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]
#Create a row index
df$idx <- 1:NROW(df)
rowidxs <- with(df,  unique( c(    # the `c` function will make a matrix into a vector
              tapply(idx, list( group1,  group2),
                            function (x) resample(x, 1) ))))
rowidxs
# [1]  1  5 NA 12 16 NA  3 15  6  4 14 10 NA NA  7 NA NA  8
df[rowidxs[!is.na(rowidxs)] , ]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I extended the answer to demonstrate how `tapply` can be employed for sampling.